# Inmutable values mutating in IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, des

So, I've been trying to figure out the following problem for the past few weeks, and at this point I'm almost exhausting my options because how contradictory the situation seems.

I have an application which is developed to work under SharePoint but it's basically ASP.NET code. I have an encrypted connection string which I decrypt it in memory and store it in a configuration object to access the database. My configuration object is static (accesible through a `Service Locator` pattern), which I later use to seed a LINQ-to-SQL data context.

My internal key for decryption is stored, privately in a class as `private static readonly string myPassword = "MyPassword";` (just an example, the actual password is more complex and valid). There's no single statement, anywhere, referencing that field, except one on a static method using it as a parameter for another decryption method (instance method), which instantiates a new `DESCryptoServiceProvider` with it.

And still, I get the following exception from time to time in my production server logs:

```
Exception type: CryptographicException
Exception message: Specified key is a known weak key for 'DES' and cannot be used.
```

As such, the connection string decryption fails and, of course, the database is not accessed anymore. Poof, application down.

How is this even possible?

**Disclaimer**: This is an old application I am maintaining. The description I provide here is to help troubleshoot, but I cannot change the way it works internally. Some will agree that this is not the best approach but the application has been running without a problem for more than 2 years and suddenly these exceptions are taking it down.

**Update**: I've been requested to clarify with a stack trace of the exception, but I cannot provide one full stack trace for NDA reasons. What I *can* tell is the following:

- The object throwing the exception is the `System.Security.DESCryptoServiceProvider.CreateDecryptor(Byte[] rgbKey, Byte[] rgbIV)` method
- The original key (the one we actually use) does validate and does not generate an exception. Still, we get this exception from time to time (not always), without knowing which is the current value which does not validate
- The instance of the `DESCryptoServiceProvider` is stored statically, privately, in a helper class
- This is all triggered by `System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon()`, to initialize the application internal parts

Also, here is an obscured stack trace:

```
at System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider.CreateDecryptor(Byte[] rgbKey, Byte[] rgbIV)
at SymmetricEncryption.Decrypt(String contents, String key)
// our helper, just a wrapper, based from this class: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1967/Encryption-Decryption-with-NET
at EncryptedConnectionStringHelper.DecryptUserAndPass(String connectionString)\
// our container for parsing the connection string and decrypting the user and password, not the full connstring is encrypted
at OurModule.Init(OurConfigurationSection config)
at OurModule.Boot(OurConfigurationSection config)
at OurModule.Boot()
at OurModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
```

Our application registers this module in the following way:

```
public class OurModule : IHttpModule
{
    public static bool initialized = false;

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    { 
        if (!initialized) {
            subscribe(context);
            OurModule.Boot();
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you decrypt it once and for all when application starts ?

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet Hi! I actually do, and store the connection string. I assume (I may be wrong here) that this gets re-initialize everytime the app starts again or the app pool recycles.

Comment: Can you recreate a new encrypted string with a stronger key that is less likely to be a known weak key.

Comment: I doubt your string is being mutated. At the point of error the code is hitting the Microsoft CSP for DES, it's a signed Microsoft Assembly  and has a bunch of restrictions around how it's used/weather it's been changed/tampered with etc.  I think the exception is thrown from the CSP. I don't think you're going to find an answer.

Comment: @Hath I certainly can. I was trying to avoid that since it is a hassle for the cascading changes, and (most importantly) does not solve the issue. Is it possible for a key to be detected as weak depending on the initialization vector?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your wrapper `SymmetricEncryption.Decrypt`. My guess would be that the issue is in there. How it creates the Key from your password. Does it use [PasswordDeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx) or some other half baked solution?

Failing that maybe you could try get a better key than "MyPassword".

Failing that maybe you could use web.config encryption. [Scott Gu wrote about it here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx)

Comment: This is my guess also.  Is SymmetricEncryption.Decrypt deterministic?  You assume it is, but are you sure?

Comment: That class (a link to a previous implementation is in the original question) is nothing more than a wrapper to several encryption providers. In this case, I'm using it for DES.
I have checked how it generates keys, and while it is supsicious (it makes the provide generate a key to complete the valid key length of the original password), my key is long enough to be used directly. So, in fact, my key is truncated and it is always the same. The IV is always the same too.

Thanks for the advice. I will keep looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like anything's *mutating* the object. It sounds like "something" (if you'd posted the stack trace it would be clearer) is *validating* the DES key... and complaining that it's a known weak key.

Ideally, you should change your password to be more secure, of course - but if you can't, you should look at exactly where that exception's coming from, and see if there are settings somewhere controlling how and when it's validated.

If you're not already logging the full stack trace (instead of just the exception message) that's the *first* thing you should do.

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you very much for the response. The very same .NET `DESCryptoServiceProvider` contains a validation for the key, and that is the one throwing the exception. The confusing part for me is that the validation with the real key is valid, but I still get these exceptions.

Comment: @Alpha: What do you mean by "the validation with the real key is valid"? If the real key is "MyPassword" that sounds like just the kind of thing which could be a known weak key...

Comment: I provided more details in the question. Not a stack trace, but I think it may help. The validation with the original Key (e.g. "MyPassword") does validate, and actually does work (it has for over 2 years). It still does. From time to time (and not always) I get the exception saying that the key (not sure of it's value at that moment) is a DES weak key. That makes me think that the key is somehow changing.

Comment: @Alpha: If you think it's changing, then you should add logging *just before* that point. I suspect it's more likely that there's some sort of heuristics involved in the validation. Can you really not even say which method throws the exception? If not, I don't think I can help you any further.

Comment: I had added more details. I hope they suffice. Again, thanks for the help. :)